# Alternate solution for making multiple copies of a single file using command line?

Tags: command-line, files, cp

I am trying to copy a file to 10 files. Say for example I have a E-mail message named `test1.eml`. I want 10 copies of the same file.

When I searched in internet, I came across this stackoverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550540/linux-commands-to-copy-one-file-to-many-files and followed the eval command mentioned by one of the community member 'knittl'.

```
eval 'cp test1.eml 'test{2..10}.eml';'
```

The above mentioned command worked and it met my requirements. 
Are there any other alternative/more elegant commands to achieve this, since the person who mentioned about eval command told it's kind of a dirty hack.

Comment: Are you sure you want to copy the file (and it's content) or would some symlinks (or maybe even hard links) match your purpose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do something like `for i in {2..10}; do cp test1.eml test$i.eml; done`
Yet is more or less the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Svetlin and don_crissti. That's a simple and small solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
 tee >test2.eml test{3..10}.eml < test1.xml
```

would only read the source once and execute only one command. It might not be more efficient for large files and could encourage fragmentation as `tee` would write blocks of data in each output file in turn. It also creates files with permissions according to your current umask instead of partly or completely reproducing the original permissions as `cp` does depending on options.

If you want to save typing, just use `zsh` as your shell (that's where those `{2..10}` constructs come from btw)

```
 for f (test{2..10}.eml)cp test1.eml $f
```

Which is as short as your:

```
 eval 'cp test1.eml 'test{2..10}.eml';'
```

yet more intuitive/legible and more easily generalisable to file names with more problematic characters.

With `zsh` and assuming you've not disabled the `multios` option, you can also do:

```
<test1.eml >test{2..10}.eml
```

There, `zsh` does the `tee` internally and also invokes `cat`. So it's slightly less efficient than the `tee` approach.